# Sphinx doesn't show almost all data in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

I use sphinx + thinking_sphinx on my local machine and met really strange problem.

I have 2 models - Users and Microposts. Sphinx gets and show users but it can't find Microposts on my Production machine. On my local my machine it does.

In production i try:

```
root@serverserj:/vol/www/apps/ror_tutorial/current# rake ts:config
Generating Configuration to /vol/www/apps/ror_tutorial/releases/20120125204127/config/development.sphinx.conf

root@serverserj:/vol/www/apps/ror_tutorial/current# rake ts:index
Generating Configuration to /vol/www/apps/ror_tutorial/releases/20120125204127/config/development.sphinx.conf
Sphinx 2.0.3-release (r3043)
Copyright (c) 2001-2011, Andrew Aksyonoff
Copyright (c) 2008-2011, Sphinx Technologies Inc (http://sphinxsearch.com)

using config file '/vol/www/apps/ror_tutorial/releases/20120125204127/config/development.sphinx.conf'...
indexing index 'micropost_core'...
WARNING: collect_hits: mem_limit=0 kb too low, increasing to 13568 kb
collected 0 docs, 0.0 MB
total 0 docs, 0 bytes
total 0.012 sec, 0 bytes/sec, 0.00 docs/sec
skipping non-plain index 'micropost'...
indexing index 'user_core'...
WARNING: collect_hits: mem_limit=0 kb too low, increasing to 13568 kb
collected 1 docs, 0.0 MB
sorted 0.0 Mhits, 100.0% done
total 1 docs, 12 bytes
total 0.012 sec, 1000 bytes/sec, 83.33 docs/sec
skipping non-plain index 'user'...
total 4 reads, 0.000 sec, 0.0 kb/call avg, 0.0 msec/call avg
total 14 writes, 0.000 sec, 0.0 kb/call avg, 0.0 msec/call avg
rotating indices: succesfully sent SIGHUP to searchd (pid=1959).

root@serverserj:/vol/www/apps/ror_tutorial/current $ rake ts:rebuild
Stopped search daemon (pid 1959).
Generating Configuration to /vol/www/apps/ror_tutorial/releases/20120125204127/config/development.sphinx.conf
Sphinx 2.0.3-release (r3043)
Copyright (c) 2001-2011, Andrew Aksyonoff
Copyright (c) 2008-2011, Sphinx Technologies Inc (http://sphinxsearch.com)
using config file '/vol/www/apps/ror_tutorial/releases/20120125204127/config/development.sphinx.conf'...
indexing index 'micropost_core'...
WARNING: collect_hits: mem_limit=0 kb too low, increasing to 13568 kb
collected 0 docs, 0.0 MB
total 0 docs, 0 bytes
total 0.012 sec, 0 bytes/sec, 0.00 docs/sec
skipping non-plain index 'micropost'...
indexing index 'user_core'...
WARNING: collect_hits: mem_limit=0 kb too low, increasing to 13568 kb
collected 1 docs, 0.0 MB
sorted 0.0 Mhits, 100.0% done
total 1 docs, 12 bytes
total 0.008 sec, 1500 bytes/sec, 125.00 docs/sec
skipping non-plain index 'user'...
total 4 reads, 0.000 sec, 0.0 kb/call avg, 0.0 msec/call avg
total 14 writes, 0.000 sec, 0.0 kb/call avg, 0.0 msec/call avg
Started successfully (pid 2218).
```

For example, lets try something on local machine:

```
$ rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 3.1.3)
system :001 > Micropost.search 'Minus'
   (0.3ms)  SHOW search_path
  Sphinx Query (2.3ms)  Minus
  Sphinx  Found 12 results
  Micropost Load (1.6ms)  SELECT "microposts".* FROM "microposts" WHERE "microposts"."id" IN (30, 32, 91, 106, 121, 128, 160, 171, 172, 239, 258, 260) ORDER BY microposts.created_at DESC
 => [#<Micropost id: 30, content: "Sed minus magni culpa reiciendis unde.", user_id: 1, created_at: "2012-01-15 21:11:03", updated_at: "2012-01-15 21:11:03">, #<Micropost id: 32, content: "Placeat pariatur quisquam provident velit veniam vo...", user_id: 1, created_at: "2012-01-15 21:11:03", updated_at: "2012-01-15 21:11:03">...]
```

And on production machine:

```
$ rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 3.1.3)
1.9.1 :001 > Micropost.search 'Minus'
   (4.0ms)  SHOW search_path
  Sphinx Query (4.0ms)  Minus
  Sphinx  Found 0 results
 => []
```

**config/deploy.rb**

```
#Add RVM's lib directory to the load path.
$:.unshift(File.expand_path('./lib', ENV['rvm_path']))

#Load RVM's capistrano plugin.    
require "rvm/capistrano"
require 'bundler/capistrano'
#require 'thinking_sphinx/deploy/capistrano'

set :rvm_ruby_string, '1.9.3-head'                                            #This is current version of ruby which is uses by RVM. To get version print: $ rvm list 
set :rvm_type, :root                                                          #Don't use system-wide RVM, use my user, which name is root.

set :user, "root"                                                             #If you log into your server with a different user name than you are logged into your local machine with, you’ll need to tell Capistrano about that user name.
set :rails_env, "production"

set :application, "ror_tutorial"
set :deploy_to, "/vol/www/apps/#{application}"

set :scm, :git
set :repository,  "git://github.com/Loremaster/sample_app.git"
set :branch, "master"
set :deploy_via, :remote_cache
default_run_options[:pty] = true                                              #Must be set for the password prompt from git to work#Keep cash of repository locally and with ney deploy get only changes.


server "188.127.224.136", :app,                                               # This may be the same as your `Web` server
                          :web,
                          :db, :primary => true                               # This is where Rails migrations will run



# If you are using Passenger mod_rails uncomment this:
namespace :deploy do
   task :start do ; end
   task :stop do ; end
   task :restart, :roles => :app, :except => { :no_release => true } do
     run "#{try_sudo} touch #{File.join(current_path,'tmp','restart.txt')}"
   end
end


desc "Prepare system"
  task :prepare_system, :roles => :app do
    run "cd #{current_path} && bundle install --without development test && bundle install --deployment"
  end

  after "deploy:update_code", :prepare_system
```

My System

```
Ubuntu 10.04.1 LTS 
Phusion Passenger 
PostgreSQL 9 
Nginx 
Rails 3.1.3 
Ruby 1.9.3
Capistrano
Sphinx 2.0.3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like that you don't have documents for micropost_core index:

```
using config file '/vol/www/apps/ror_tutorial/releases/20120125204127/config/development.sphinx.conf'...
indexing index 'micropost_core'...
WARNING: collect_hits: mem_limit=0 kb too low, increasing to 13568 kb
collected 0 docs, 0.0 MB
total 0 docs, 0 bytes
total 0.012 sec, 0 bytes/sec, 0.00 docs/sec
skipping non-plain index 'micropost'...
```

There is 0 docs. Could you please provide config, and check your data on production?